# Spring boot multiple authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication

I've done a spring boot application with spring security integration and a custom Authentication Provider. Now I want that some link are going to use custom Authent provider and some other an inmemory authentication. How can I do that?

Comment: Hello @rovell74, so from what i understand you want to have some path /url_to_be_secured_with_spring and other like /url_to_be_secure_with_custom_provider ? i'm right ? if so maybe you can give more info about the purpose of such a behaviour? Anyway, you can exclude path from spring security, and then deal with security manually (but i will nor recommend at all). Can you provide some code or example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Here is my SecurityConfig class. Now i want protect path like '/api/**' with a basic authentication.

```
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
CustomLogoutSuccessHandler  customLogoutSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAutheincationSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/list/**").hasAnyAuthority("Administrator","Operator")
        .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
        .successHandler(customAutheincationSuccessHandler)
        .and().logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: Ok not sure if the proper way to go, but you can add a customFilter to security chain and decide build your own authentication and store it in the SecurityContextHolder()
to help you can see in this class of spring:
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter
And here to create your own CustomFilter : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter

Answer (score 0):

You can create two spring security configurations with different paths. In first configuration u can exclude /api/**. But second configuration will be able to check it.